# R how to find any months in a column

Tags: r

I have a column of random words, and some words contain the months (it could be anything such as Jan, or Dec), I want to be able to find those row numbers with months name. How can I do that?

```
df = tibble(word=c("asd","May","jbsd"))
grepl(c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May", etc), df[["word"]])
```

Comment: Do you mean `which(df$word %in% month.abb)` ?

Comment: Yes! thanks, you can post it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `which` with `%in%` to get the row number of the match.

```
which(df$word %in% month.abb)
#[1] 2
```

Note that `mont.abb` is locale-specific so if `df$word` is in English it is expected that your system locale is of the same language.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: just saw the comments, I let mine in case you want to have the month name

Using `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(rownumber = row_number()) %>% 
  filter(word %in% month.abb)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  word  rownumber
  <chr>     <int>
1 May           2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to know the row number for the word it's in and not just the word.

Comment: Just edited, I'll let mine in case you want the month name with its row index. But if you just want the row number, RonakShah idea is more efficient @SubaruSpirit